# Angular Initialization errors in app.js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

So I am trying to jump on the Angular bandwagon, and I have been tasked with building an SPA, for which I have selected AngularJS with ASP.Net MVC Web API (I am a .Net developer). As a fan of strongly typed languages, I have avoided javascript whenever possible throughout my career, but frameworks like AngularJS and the other libraries & plugins in recent years have made it impossible to ignore. So here I am, asking for some guidance.

I have watched the tutorials, done the sample code projects and done some learning on PluralSight, and I have things working, at least from a foundational perspective. I have a rich background in MVVM and MVC, so SOC is a big thing for me. I like the MVC type of structure that Angular provides, which is largely why I went this route in the first place.

Now let me get to my issue(s). I am initializing my module (currently) in my master page (_Layout.cshtml), which I did while tweaking and experimenting, for the sake of simplicity.

```
<script>
    angular.module('xcmApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'companiesController',
                templateUrl: 'views/companylist.html'
            })
            .when('/Reports',
            {
                controller: 'reportsController',
                templateUrl: 'views/reportlist.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
        })
        .factory('companiesFactory', ['$resource',
            function ($resource) {
                return $resource('/api/companies', {}, {
                    query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
                });
            }
        ])
        .controller('companiesController', function ($scope, companiesFactory) {
            $scope.Companies = companiesFactory.query();
    });

</script>
```

But now that I am ready to move on to deeper concepts, I want to break my scripts out into their appropriate files. Namely, app.js and associated controllers/factories/services etc. However when I move that script into app.js and reference it in _Layout.cshtml, it errors:

```
<script src="~/app.js"></script>
```

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: a

Now there's no point in continuing to break out into controller files etc. when I can't even get the app.js to work right, so here I am stuck. I know there are some brilliant AngularJS devs on here that probably know what I'm missing before even reading this far, and I am grateful for your assistance.

Anyone who can highlight my oversight will be a superstar for me today. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is my Stack Trace:

```
    0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module xcmApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: a
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=a
   at Anonymous function (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:4015:13)
   at getService (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:4162:11)
   at invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:4191:9)
   at runInvokeQueue (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:4109:11)
   at Anonymous function (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:4118:11)
   at forEach (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:323:11)
   at loadModules (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:4099:5)
   at createInjector (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:4025:3)
   at doBootstrap (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:1452:5)
   at bootstrap (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:1473:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=xcmApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20a%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.15%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Da%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.js%3A4015%3A13)%0A%20%20%20at%20getService%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.js%3A4162%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.js%3A4191%3A9)%0A%20%20%20at%20runInvokeQueue%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.js%3A4109%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.js%3A4118%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.js%3A323%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.js%3A4099%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.js%3A4025%3A3)%0A%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.js%3A1452%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.js%3A1473%3A5)
```

REMINDER:

My problem is not that it doesn't work, it DOES WORK. It just STOPS working when I take the Javascript out of my HTML page and place it into a referenced app.js file.

Comment: Are you using a minified version of Angular? If you use the unminified version of angular.js, you get a more detailed error that could help you out.

Comment: I am using unminified Angular: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the documentation. You are using a bad way of defining your application. Try:

```
var MyApp = angular.module( 'MyApp', ['ngRoute' , 'ngSanitize']) ;
```

and then use `MyApp` to add controllers, filters, etc.

EDIT:

BTW, it is a good practice to write the Javascripts in separate files for SPA (you are not writing a small project I guess).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but even defining the module as you suggest, results in the error I mentioned above:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a few declaration pieces related to Dependency Injection in your controller definition.

Before I post the specific code and fixes, I want to mention a useful troubleshooting tool for Dependency Injection issues.  Angular has a built in directive `ng-strict-di`.  This directive is a companion to `ng-app`.  From the [`ng-app` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp#!):

> if this attribute is present on the app element, the injector will be created in "strict-di" mode. This means that the application will fail to invoke functions which do not use explicit function annotation (and are thus unsuitable for minification), as described in [the Dependency Injection guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), and useful debugging info will assist in tracking down the root of these bugs.

Now, to the code in your post:

Your controller is not using explicit function annotation.  In explicit function annotation, you pass a string array of dependencies, followed by the function.  This ensures that even if minification were to rename the function parameters, Angular can still identify which dependency to supply to the function.  You have used explicit annotation in parts of your code, but it is missing from your controller definition.

This is classically easy to identify, with `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: a`, even though you never defined a provider named `a`.  `ng-strict-di` would flag this controller code.

Here is the current code, and the proposed fix.

Instead of:

```
.controller('companiesController', function ($scope, companiesFactory) {
```

Try:

```
.controller('companiesController', ['$scope', 'companiesFactory', function ($scope, companiesFactory) {
```

Comment: I changed controller declaration as suggested, and the result is the same when I move the script out of my HTML page and into the referenced app.js. I was able to obtain the entire stack trace, which is not very valuable to me with my limited Angular (and admittedly JS) exposure, but maybe it means something to you: (TOO LONG FOR A COMMENT, I WILL EDIT OP)

Comment: you also are not using this form in the `.config` block; can you try changing that, and also checking to see if `ng-strict-di` gives you any new information?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have an ASP.net background, but I think that souldn't matter to answer your Angular question.

First declare your modules like this:

```
angular.module('myModule', []);
```

and get them im oder files like this:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller/foactory/....
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
//xcmApp.module.js
angular.module('xcmApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

//xcmApp.config.js
angular.module('xcmApp').config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'companiesController',
                templateUrl: 'views/companylist.html'
            })
        .when('/Reports',
            {
                controller: 'reportsController',
                templateUrl: 'views/reportlist.html'
            })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
});

//xcmApp.factory.js
angular.module('xcmApp').factory('companiesFactory', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/companies', {}, {
            query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true}
        });
    }
]);

//xcmApp.controller.js
angular.module('xcmApp').controller('companiesController', function ($scope, companiesFactory) {
    $scope.Companies = companiesFactory.query();
});
```

EDIT:

Regarding the error, keep in mind that your dependencies must be in the rigth order.
So your index.html (assuming you use don't use a script loader yet)  should look like this:

```
<script src="/*path to angular*/"></script>
<script src="/*path to ngRoute*/"></script>
<script src="/*path to ngResource*/"></script>

<script src="/*path to xcmApp.module.js*/"></script> //setting your app module must come first
<script src="/*path to xcmApp.config.js*/"></script>
<script src="/*path to xcmApp.factory.js*/"></script> //must come before the controller in your case
<script src="/*path to xcmApp.controller.js*/"></script>
```

Comment: I am using CDN for the Angular libraries, so the head of my HTML host page has the following references:

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>. As for the other JS references, I am using Grunt to combine and minify my scripts, and so all source scripts end up minified in app.js output file. I am fairly certain this is not the cause of my error.

Comment: Why did I get downvotes for this answer? I'm here on Stack Overflow to learn and share knowledge. So if this answer is wrong, please tell me why.